# Randomly selecting a word from a dictionary with a given probability

Tags: python, random

I have a dictionary that has words and their probabilities of being selected as below:

```
dic = {'A': 0.2, 'B': 0.45, 'C': 0.35}
```

I want to randomly select 1 word based on its associated probability. So 'B' being selected would have highest probability. I've tried to use `random.choice` and `random.choices` but it isn't working. This is what I've tried:

```
next_word = random.choices(dic.keys(), weights=dic.values(), k=1)
```

I get `TypeError: 'dict_keys' object is not subscriptable`

Please suggest how I can do this.

Comment: "they don't seem to be the right option" is not the description of an error. Please make a clear problem description.

Comment: Alright fixed language sir. And added explicit error message.

Comment: `dic.keys()` and `dic.values()` do not support indexing. You can convert them to lists. `list(dic.keys())` and `list(dic.values())`

Comment: Please read [ask]. Add a full traceback. Add details of other things you tried.

Answer (score 2):

```
import random
dic = {'A': 0.2, 'B': 0.45, 'C': 0.35}
next_word = random.choices(list(dic.keys()), weights=list(dic.values()), k=1)
next_word
```

Answer (score 0):

You are definitely on the right track. But you can do this to make it right:

```
next_word = random.choices(list(dic.keys()), weights=dic.values(), k=1)[0]
```